# difference between e.preventDefault() and event.preventDefault()?

Tags: jquery, events

Is there any difference between these two?  Or is just one an abbreviation of the other?

```
e.preventDefault() and event.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, the only difference is the name of event object that is being passed into your listener. If you declare the listener like this:

```
a.click(function(e) {
});
```

Obviously the name of event variable is "e" and you should call e.preventDefault. In the second case:

```
a.click(function(event) {
});
```

the name of the event object is "event", so you're calling event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 1):

e is just an abbreviation for event, it depends on how the argument is accepted

Comment: Thats what i thought!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of variable naming. Some people's convention is naming their event variable e, ev, or event. Whichever best suits you.